# Replication postgresql database error connection between master to standby

Tags: database, postgresql, replication, database-replication, zabbix

Dear all I have found this issue, while I trying to do replication postgresql database. I have run this command *pg_basebackup -h 192.168.47.155 -D /var/lib/postgresql/data -U replicator -P -v  -R -X stream -C -S pgstandby1*, then the output *pg_basebackup: error: connection to server at "192.168.47.155", port 5432 failed: Network unreachable
Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?* anyone have any idea to solve this?
Thank in advance,

regards,
chhunnet

I have stop firewall on each instance, and try to telnet with port 5432 but it not work.
I also add this text into file pg_hba.conf >> *host    replication     zabbix          192.168.xx.xxx/24       md5*

Comment: That's a network configuration question, off-topic here.